# Android Studio Gradle 1.1 and Roboeletric

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, gradle

i'm having a hard time to make AS with gradle 1.1 work with Roboeletric. I've readed a few tutorials e try some things but none seen to work.

This is my Project build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The robo eletric got download and all and here is my module build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.boozeprice"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

    compile project(':androidcore')
    compile project(':persistencecore')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
}
```

The gradle compiles and all but it seens that i don't have the library in project, i can't import the roboeletric classes neither their annotations.

Am i missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to make it work was to change this line on the gradle file:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
```

To this:

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4
```

And now works like a charm